# Run powershell script from commandline, pass in directory as paramater and use a Get-Date to format date

Tags: powershell

I want to run a script from commandline, which takes in a file directory as one of the parameters. The files are log files, which are postfixed by a date in following format: yyymmdd (Get-Date -Format filedate). I want to get the latest log file to be passed into the pwoershell script. e.g *logfile-20210928.json*

```
> e.g powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy
> RemoteSigned -File "D:\someapp\checkfile.ps1" -Path
> 'D:\logs\logfile-$(Get-Date -Format filedate).json'
```

I get the following error as powershell thinks -Format is a parameter.

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
> '-Format'.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there were format keywords like filedate.  There's no command completion for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting your 'Get-Date' part in single quotes, the variable is therefor plain text.
try:

```
"D:\logs\logfile-$(Get-Date -Format filedate).json"
```

Since you are using cmd to open the file you can not use powershell's Get-Date function in the commandline, you can try:

```
D:\logs\logfile-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.json
```

So the .bat file will be:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "D:\someapp\checkfile.ps1" -Path "D:\logs\logfile-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.json"
```

And the powershell file will be:

```
param($path)
write-host $path
```

Output from cmd when running the .bat file:

> D:\logs\logfile-20210928.json

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried that. But it is looking for a file named D:\logs\logfile-$(Get-Date -Format filedate).json . Instead of D:\logs\logfile-20210928.json

Answer (score 1):

You can run as command instead of file:

```
# checkfile.ps1
param($path)
"path is $path"
```

```
powershell .\checkfile logfile-$(Date -F filedate).json

path is logfile-20210928.json
```